# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in an inline javascript function with multi line string argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a prepended `tr` with an inline `javascript` function with a multi line string argument.

```
function htmlEncodeMyUnsolved(obj) {
    $('#my-unsolved-reminder-list').prepend(`
        <tr id= "`+ obj.id +`" class ="unsolved-notif" onclick= "viewNote('`+ obj.message +`', `+ obj.id +`)" >\
            <td class ="mailbox-name"><a href="read-mail.html">`+ obj.fromUser +`</a></td>\
            <td class ="mailbox-subject">\
                `+ obj.message +`
            </td>\
            <td class ="mailbox-attachment"></td>\
            <td class ="mailbox-date text-right"> `+ obj.dateAndTime +` </td>\
        </tr>\
    `);
}
```

this is how it looks in browser inspector:

```
<tr id="1026" class="unsolved-notif" onclick="viewNote('asd
sdf
sea
qwe')">
```

And this is the `viewNote` function:

```
function viewNote(note) {
    $('p#message').text(note);
}
```

when i try to click th `tr` i'm getting an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`, what i'm trying is i want to display multi line text in a `p` tag. how fix this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the whole string? Or if it's really long, show a section of the string that you would expect to work properly but doesn't?

Comment: Can you please show the full line of JS code?

Comment: How about `obj.message.replace(/\n/g, '\\n')`

Comment: still getting the error, i'm getting the error in the inline function

Comment: The `viewNote()` function declaration doesn't seem relevant. Again, can you please show the full line of JS code that creates the TR?

Comment: Is `obj.message` a multi-line string? I think that might be your issue. (Oh, just saw that @BrettZamir kind of pointed that out.)

Comment: ` or ' There is a difference in those types quotes.  Make sure you are using '. If you are editing your code in a word processor, it might be switching them.

Comment: Backticks (`\``) are fine these days. Though they aren't being used to their fullest potential in this case (no need for trailing backslashes or using `+`, etc.)

Comment: @DonovanM yes it is a multi-line string, in server side (c#) the message value is `"asd\nsdf\nsea\nqwe"` but in browser inspector it's converted to new line which is shown in my question

Comment: In `htmlEncodeMyUnsolved` I believe if you change `obj.message` to what @BrettZamir posted, things should work. That should change it back to `asd\nsdf\nsea\nqwe`.

Comment: Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Reduce your code to just what is required to reproduce the error and post it as a runnable snippet. I doubt that you can have multi-line strings inside HTML attribute values.

Comment: @DonovanM Thank you for your replies, i finally fixed the problem

Comment: using @BrettZamir comment :)

Comment: Great to hear! :)

Comment: Good to hear--I added as an answer so the question could be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the following:

```
obj.message.replace(/\n/g, '\\n')
```

...it will ensure that the rendered string will escape the new lines (though JavaScript still supplies them to your function as newlines).